# VS Code audio cues won't turn off in workspace

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, macos-monterey

I can't seem to get VS Code to stop playing audio cues every time I mouse over an error or warning or, well, presumably any one of the seven cue types.

#### Tried so far

- Turn all audioCue settings to Off in User Settings
- Turn all audioCue settings to Off in Workspace Settings
- `>Developer: Reload with extensions disabled`

Ideally, I'd like to configure the editor to behave properly, but if it's an editor bug, then suggestions for how to selectively disable audio for a single app in macOS would be much appreciated! (It's driving me kinda crazy.)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR —   `"audioCues.enabled": "off"`

I'd been ignoring that setting since it's deprecated…

[image: Screenshot of entry in VS Code Settings that reads, "Edit in settings.json" and "Deprecated. Use the specific setting for each audio cue instead (audioCues.*)."]

…and apparently, in this case, that was a mistake. Once I clicked through to `settings.json` and changed it from `"audioCues.enabled": "on"` to `"audioCues.enabled": "off"`, all was well again with the world.

Upon further reflection, this seems like an editor bug, in that it violates the Law of Least Surprise.

That said, I'm not planning to report it [on the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) as it'll hopefully die a natural death once the deprecated setting has been excised. With any luck, no one will have this issue but me. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

[It sounds like you have discovered a bug in the editor - disabling those specific audio cues should work... or `auto` if no screen reader.]

Beside disabling any specific audio cue, there is a new volume level setting that can be set to `0` in v1.66 (see [v1.66 release notes, audio cues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#audio-cues-improvements)):

> Audio Cues Improvements
>
> The new setting `audioCues.volume` (0-100, default is 50) can be used
> to control the volume of audio cues. We also updated the audio cue for
> folded regions.

You can individually disable these:

```
Audio Cues: Line Has Breakpoint  
Audio Cues: Line Has Error  
Audio Cues: Line Has Folded Areas  
Audio Cues: Line Has Inline Suggestion  
Audio Cues: Line Has Warning  
Audio Cues: No Inlay Hints  
Audio Cues: On Debug Break
```